# Fazer com que o console pegue um valor de outra classe em C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando aprender linguagem C#. Nesse caso estou tentando fazer com que o Console mostre o valor do saldo, pegando esse valor de uma classe diferente no mesmo arquivo (já tentei com múltiplos-arquivos e mesmo assim não dá certo, o compilador não vê a variável).

```
using System;
using namespaceb;

namespace namespaceb
{
    public class saldo
    {
       public int numero = 100;
    }
}

namespace namespacea
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            saldo teste = new saldo();
            Console.WriteLine(numero); //dá erro "O nome Numero não existe no contexto atual"
            Console.WriteLine(teste); // mostra uma linha "namespaceb.saldo"
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se a classe estiver no mesmo `namespace` você pode usar ela `saldo s = new saldo();` em seguida `s.numero`

Comment: só ta faltando `Console.WriteLine(teste.numero);`

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using namespaceb;

namespace namespaceb
{
    public class saldo
    {
       public int numero = 100;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            saldo teste = new saldo();
            Console.WriteLine(teste.numero);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```